# Git and Visual Studio 2015 behind corporate firewall and proxy

Tags: git, proxy, visual-studio-2015, firewall

We're developing behind a corporate firewall and proxy server. Amongst the various problems we are facing right now is with Visual Studio 2015 using Git.

When I try to do a sync I'm getting the following error on the push:

```
Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
```

Specifically for the push:

```
Chunked encoding upload is not supported on the HTTP/1.0 protocol.
```

[image: Failed to push to the remote repository...]

[image: Chunked encoding upload is not supported...]

### The question:

The problem is pretty much that I don't know what to ask for to the IT department precisely.

Ideally there would be a well-known solution that would allow for seamless use of major development tools.

Up until now most of the job done in the office did not require major access to the general internet and there is a very strict security policy on this regard due to the confidentiality of the information we handle.

I could certainly hand the problem in to them and wait forever, but I would like to be better prepared to explain what is it that we need to do on the proxy servers or firewalls in general.

Thanks and I hope the question makes sense as stated.

Comment: Isn't this a question for your IT department?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You're right, I pressed the send button without having asked the question yet...

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Push does not work via Visual Studio, but it works via command-line though.